# prevent node overlap on add new node

Tags: cytoscape.js

how do i prevent from overlapping new added nodes in cytoscape js graph?
i do not want change position of existing nodes
i want new adding nodes do automatically position by this rule that preventing  existing node overlap

when i use add API to add nodes to graph added nodes overlap others
how can i change this behavior?
is there a solution for prevent node overlap in adding mode (new node do not overlap existing node)?

```
cy.add([
  {  data: {label:"aaa" ,id:"bbb" } },
  { data: {label:"aaa333"  ,id:"rrrr"} },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in solution. I just look for an empty spot using this code for testing overlap (this is given a fixed node size, you could adapt it for using bounding boxes, but that slows things down).

```js
  function overlap(pos, size) {
  var overlap = false;
  cy.nodes(':visible').forEach(function (node) {
    var npos = node.position();
    if ((pos.x - size) < npos.x && (pos.x + size) > npos.x && (pos.y - size) < npos.y && (pos.y + size) > npos.y) {
      overlap = true;
      return false; //break
     }
  });
  return overlap;
}
```

I use this with the prefered position as first argument ({x:..,y:..}), and when that fails I just add 10 to y to see if it fitst. Wether this is the best solution for you depends on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an automated way of doing this, your best bet is a force-directed/physics layout.

Lock all but the new nodes when you run the layout.

You'll have to experiment with different layouts to see which particular one suits your app/data best.